# Push Notification Error in Amazon EC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting following error on sending push notification, I think there is some permission access problem.

I am using this following link code.
[iPhone Push Notification Problem with c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557890/iphone-push-notification-problem-with-c-sharp)

getting error on line:

```
sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(apsHost, certs, SslProtocols.Default, false);

System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized\r\n at System.Net.SSPIWrapper.AcquireCredentialsHandle(SSPIInterface SecModule, String package, CredentialUse intent, SecureCredential scc)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Please start service from services.msc:

1) click on run command and enter services.msc or open services .
2) start service and stratup type is automatic mode for all below services :
    a)  Cryptographic Services
    b) ASP.NET State Service
    c) Credential Manager
    d) Health Key and Certificate Management
```